# Regex replace word after fixed string

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a string like this

*some text* **"myKey":myValue,** *some other text*

I'd like to find all the occourrence of **"mykey":myValue,** and replace with

*fixedText1* **"myKey"** *fixedText2* : *fixedText3* **myValue** *fixedText4*

I kwon the keys to change but not the values... (the keys are fixed)

briefly I'like to surround the key and the value with some html tag, only for a specific key.

Can you help me to find a regular ex that match?

I try to start from this example in javascript with 2 word without success

```
var re = /(\w+)\s(\w+)/;
var str = "zara ali";
var newstr = str.replace(re, "$2, $1");
```

Thanks a lot!

Alessandro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"([^"]+)"[ :]+"?([\w+ ]+)"?
```

This regex will capture keys/values similar to

```
"myKey":myValue
"anotherKey": Another Value
"myNewKey": "New Value"
"numberKey" : 23
```

It assumes the `key` is surrounded by double-quotes but the `value` can be any word character `A-Z0-9_ or space`, optionally surrounded by double-quotes.

Then use `$1` and `$2` to insert into a new string as per your example

see [demo here](https://regex101.com/r/jN8xD7/2)

Comment: Perfect is exatcly what I need. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about awk?

```
cat test.txt | awk '{gsub(/"myKey/, "fixedText1\"myKey"); gsub(/:myValue/, "fixedText2 : fixedText3 myValue"); print'}
```

Comment: I'm using it in a javascript function... the aim is to color some specific field in a log (plain text) tha has some json write in...

Comment: I forgot... Thanks :)